# Run a bash shell script on iMac on startup

Tags: services, background-process, macos, autostart

I have a bash shell script `/var/tmp/test.sh` that runs on iMac in an infinite `while` loop.

I wish this script to run 24X7 and even when the iMac is rebooted the script should autorun.

I want to run the shell script to run 24X7 as a background process.

Can you please suggest a quick easy solution how can I?

Answer (score 1):

Apple hasn't killed `cron` (yet), and so I think you have at least two options: `cron` and `LaunchControl`.

Briefly:

- `cron` is "old-school" command-line Unix. It uses a `crontab` to define the schedule. It is free, open-source and widely used. It is easy to use - if you understand its limitations.
- [Apple's native `launchd` and `launchctl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) have more capability than `cron`, but from your question, it appears these added capabilities are not necessary. But if you're still interested, there are some things you should know. The first thing you should know is [`LaunchControl`](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/); you used the word ***easy*** in your question, and this all but eliminates `launchctl`. `LaunchControl` is a 3rd-party commercial (not free) app that provides a sane GUI scheduling mechanism for `launchd`; it is what `launchctl` ***should have been***.

### The `cron` solution:

The first step will depend on whether or not `root` (Administrator) privileges are required. Since you didn't mention that they were, we'll proceed under the assumption that user privileges are all that is required by your `sh` script:

1. From the `Terminal` app on your iMac:

```bsh
% crontab -e
```

You may receive a prompt asking you to select a default editor for your `crontab`. If you're not sure which to select, choose `nano` as your editor.

Your `crontab` will open in your chosen editor.

Add the following line to the bottom of your `crontab` file:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 10; /var/tmp/test.sh >> /Users/<YOURUSERID>/test_sh_log.txt 2>&1
```

Breaking this down:

- @reboot: tells `cron` to run the following command(s) when the system boots
- `/bin/sleep 10` tells `cron` to sleep for 10 seconds before running the next command. This may not be necessary, but if you use network services or mount file systems, the `sleep` time will give the system time to get those running before your script calls on them.
- /var/tmp/test.sh is your script, w/ execute permissions properly set.
- `>> /Users/<YOURUSERID>/test_sh_log.txt 2>&1` **redirects** any output to a convenient log file; `2>&1` gets both `stdout` & `stderr` (error messages). This is often helpful for troubleshooting, or if you wish your shell script to output anything while running.

Once you `reboot` your iMac, test.sh should begin running.

### Finally:

Apple's "*security measures*" seem to be in constant flux, and there may be additional steps required to make Apple happy. The need for these steps depends upon too many factors to cover here. If you encounter difficulties, post comments here & we'll respond.